# In Angular why we initialize every class member in constructor, please confirm?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHaQQ.png)

As constructor is a default function called by class, and NgOnInit is a default lifecycle hook called by angular component, so why we don't initialize class members in NgOnInit()?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

Comment: When you use  as arguments some directive in constructor you're injecting (not defining), see the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injecting-services)

Comment: @AlexYu No its just difference

Comment: @Eliseo I know but i am asking a bit different Question

Comment: @AbhishekUpadhyay the first answer already said: **The Constructor is a default method of the class that is executed when the class is instantiated and ensures proper initialisation of fields in the class and its subclasses.**