# Why is my Event Emitter not catching observables?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-event-emitter

I created a `ComponentMessengerService` that uses an Event Emitter to allow for communication between two child components. The `input` component is supposed to send information to the `output` component via the use of an injected service in its constructor.

An `Epic` is just a custom model I have made.

Component messenger service source code:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComponentMessengerService {
  epicNumberUpdated = new EventEmitter<string>();
  epicTitleUpdated = new EventEmitter<string>();
  epicListUpdated = new EventEmitter<Epic[]>();

  sendEpicNumber(epicNumber: string){
    this.epicNumberUpdated.emit(epicNumber);
  }

  sendEpicTitle(epicTitle: string){
    this.epicTitleUpdated.emit(epicTitle)
  }
  
  sendEpicList(epicList: Epic[]){
    this.epicListUpdated.emit(epicList)
  }
}
```

Output component source code:

```
export class OutputComponent implements OnInit {

  public epicTitle: string;
  public epicNumber: string;
  public epicList: Epic[] = [];

  constructor(private componentMessenger: ComponentMessengerService) {
    this.subscribeAll();
  }

  subscribeAll(){
    this.componentMessenger.epicListUpdated.subscribe(
      (epicList: Epic[]) => {
        this.epicList = epicList; })
    this.componentMessenger.epicTitleUpdated.subscribe(
      (epicTitle: string) => { this.epicTitle = epicTitle })
    this.componentMessenger.epicNumberUpdated.subscribe(
      (epicNumber: string) => {
        this.epicNumber = epicNumber; })
  }
}
```

The output's properties are data-bound to html elements and should be displayed once the component's properties have received the observables. I have debugged my application and can confirm that the `input` component is indeed sending the observables. Unfortunately, when I tried adding console.log() statements within the `subscribeAll()` to verify whether the event emitters were receiving any data, the line of code was never executed.

Comment: “ communication between two child components..” - are these sibblings..?

Comment: Yes, they belong to the same parent component. In addition, I have another parent component with a similar setup where the sibling components also use the same service and it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

did you try to call the subscribeAll() method in the ngOnInit ?

[Difference between Constructor and ngOnInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit)

**Update**

I would solve the problem by using "Subject" instead of EventEmitter, I think EventEmitter need to work with @Output().

Comment: I have tried it with both, actually.

Comment: I would solve the problem by using "Subject" instead of EventEmitter, I think EventEmitter need to work with @Output

Answer (score 0):

We have `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject` for it.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ComponentMessengerService {
  epicNumberUpdated$ = new Subject<string>();
  epicTitleUpdated$ = new Subject<string>();
  epicListUpdated$ = new Subject<Epic[]>();

  sendEpicNumber(epicNumber: string): void {
    this.epicNumberUpdated$.next(epicNumber);
  }

  sendEpicTitle(epicTitle: string): void {
    this.epicTitleUpdated$.next(epicTitle)
  }
  
  sendEpicList(epicList: Epic[]): void {
    this.epicListUpdated$.next(epicList)
  }
}
```

And don't forget about the unsubscription from Observables, because you can have a memory leak.

```
export class OutputComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  epicTitle: string;
  epicNumber: string;
  epicList: Epic[] = [];

  private unsubscribe$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private componentMessenger: ComponentMessengerService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    initializeListeners();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.unsubscribe$.next();
    this.unsubscribe$.complete();
  }

  private initializeListeners(): void {
    this.componentMessenger.epicListUpdated$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((epicList: Epic[]) => {
        this.epicList = epicList;
      });

    this.componentMessenger.epicTitleUpdated$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((epicTitle: string) => { 
        this.epicTitle = epicTitle;
      });

    this.componentMessenger.epicNumberUpdated$
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
      .subscribe((epicNumber: string) => {
        this.epicNumber = epicNumber;
      });
  }
}
```