# Using angular class constructor for dependencies

Tags: angular

The [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763730/difference-between-constructor-and-ngoninit) on this topic I found are about 7 years old. In summary, it's recommended to use constructor for basic property initialization, setup Dependencies Injection and tasks which are not to complex. Use `ngOnInit` for more complex initialization that involves interaction with services as http requests, @Input communication mechanism, or other Angular-specific operations.

Now it's recommended to use new `inject` function to handle angular DI, because you may encounter issues with es2022. Are the following code snippets are only a question of style or is there any other difference?

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    private service = inject(Dependency);
            
    }


export class ExampleComponent {
    private service: Dependency;
    
    constructor( ) { 
      this.service = inject(Dependency);            
    }
```

Is it recommended to pass a subscriber function inside the constructor or is this operation also a complex thing that should be defined inside `ngOnInit` function?

```
export class ExampleComponent {
    private subscription: Subscription;
    private service = inject(Dependency);

    constructor( ) { 
      this.subscription = this.service.getAnObservable().subscribe(result => {
      //do something on result
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In old typescript, the initialization of properties is, under the covers, moved to the beginning of the constructor code.

In ES2022 the initialization of properties is done *before* the constructor, not within it.

So your examples don't have a difference, and even

```js
export class ExampleComponent {
  private service = inject(Dependency);
  private widget = this.service.getWidget();
}
```

and

```js
export class ExampleComponent {
  private service: Dependency;
  private widget;

  constructor( ) { 
    this.service = inject(Dependency);
    this.widget = this.service.getWidget();
  }
}
```

are future-proof but

```js
export class ExampleComponent {
  private widget = this.service.getWidget();

  constructor(private service: Dependency) {}
}
```

probably won't work in the future but it works today because Typescript currently initializes `widget` *inside* the constructor.

As a rule, I set up observables in the constructor, but observers in ngOnInit. The way I think of it, observables are just plumbing. Until subscribed to, nothing is flowing. In contrast, before you subscribe or otherwise add an observer your component **must** be set up and ready to go! This helps avoid bugs where the code is waiting for a value that was streamed/emitted before all the plumbing was in place.

Comment: btw: If I assign subscription in ngOnInit I need definite assignment assertions or `private subscription: Subscription | undefined;`. If TypeScript wants everything to be initialized in the constructor, how can I express this without using the "!"? Is there a pattern?

Comment: Is `export class ExampleComponent {
  private widget;

  constructor(private service: Dependency) {
this.widget = service.getWidget();
}

}
` also future-proof?

Comment: Yes I think that's future -proof.

Comment: Re "btw:", why do you have a subscription? If you can, the best pattern is to define observables without subscribing, then using the async pipe in the HTML template. Otherwise, I use `private _destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

Comment: Oops, premature send. Re "btw:", why do you have a subscription? If you can, the best pattern is to define observables without subscribing, then using the async pipe in the HTML template. Otherwise, I use `private _destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject(); ngOnDestroy() { const d$ = this._destroy$; if (d$) { d$.next(); d$.complete(); } }` and then have all observables `.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))` This way I don't need to manage subscriptions at all.

Comment: "why do you have a subscription?" In the case where I want to exchange data between components (e.g. via service), where the value of data (subject) is dynamic and the other component has to listen (observe) for change.